How can I set a timeout for requests to the Next.js server?
Suppose there’s a simple Next.js (version 14.2.5) app that calls a backend API using a server action triggered by a button press. When the button is clicked, the browser sends a request to the Next.js server (the first request), and then the server calls the API (the second request). While I can set a timeout for the second request, how can I set a timeout for the first request?
I tried using maxDuration from the route segment configs in the page.tsx where the button is located, but it didn’t work. It’s worth noting that my app is self-hosted and not deployed on Vercel or any other platform. Is it necessary to deploy the app on Vercel for this configuration to function properly?
Here’s my code:
actions.ts:
export const sendRequest = async () => {
  return await fetch(url, {body, method: "POST"})
}

component.tsx:
"use client"
export default function Component() {
  return (
    <button onClick={async () => {
        await sendRequest();
      }
    <button />
  )
}

page.tsx:
export const maxDuration = 5;

export default async funciton Page() {
  return (<Component />)
}


If you use the fetch API, you can use AbortSignal.timeout.

@AhmedAbdelbaset As you can see, I’m using it in action.ts, but that applies to the second request (between the Next.js server and the backend), for which I can set a timeout. My question is about how to set a timeout for the first request (between the Next.js client and server).
